# Why is findbugs analysing classes I have told it not to?

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

I'm using the findbugs maven plugin.  Here's how my configuration looks like:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                <includeFilterFile>findbugs-include.xml</includeFilterFile>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>findbugs-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here's my findbugs-include.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <!-- these come from http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html -->
        <Bug pattern="NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR,NP_NONNULL_PARAM_VIOLATION,NP_NONNULL_RETURN_VIOLATION,NP_NULL_PARAM_DEREF,NP_NULL_PARAM_DEREF_ALL_TARGETS_DANGEROUS,NP_NULL_PARAM_DEREF_NONVIRTUAL,NP_STORE_INTO_NONNULL_FIELD,NP_METHOD_RETURN_RELAXING_ANNOTATION,NP_PARAMETER_MUST_BE_NONNULL_BUT_MARKED_AS_NULLABLE"/>
        <Package name="~com.company.app.*"/>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

But in the maven console, when I turn debug on, it has lines like this:

```
 [java] Added 3 referenced classes
 [java] Total of 71 packages
 [java]   com/company/app/client/FooBar
 [java]   java/util/HashMap
```

Why is that hashmap in there?  It's not part of the packages I told it to look into.

I should note that this is a multi-module project and this plugin is defined in my root pom.  My findbugs-include.xml is in the same folder as my root pom.  It does appear like the file is being read and the `<Bug>` element is working correctly because if I comment out either, my build fails very early.  I just don't understand why it's noticing classes outside my project like `java/util/HashMap`.

Perhaps I'm just misunderstanding the logging.  But it does say this:

```
 [java] Pass 1: Analyzing classes (20 / 1048) - 01% complete     209 usecs/byte     210 msec    1002 bytes  0 pass com/company/app/client/CreateOrUpdateProceduresResponse     6 0/2  20/1048 java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.NoteSuppressedWarnings to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.FindBugsSummaryStats to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.OverridingEqualsNotSymmetrical to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.EqualsOperandShouldHaveClassCompatibleWithThis to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.FieldItemSummary to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.FunctionsThatMightBeMistakenForProcedures to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.NoteAnnotationRetention to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.NoteDirectlyRelevantTypeQualifiers to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.BuildObligationPolicyDatabase to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.NoteJCIPAnnotation to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.Methods to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.ReflectiveClasses to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.CalledMethods to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.NoteCheckReturnValueAnnotations to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.NoteNonNullAnnotations to java/util/HashMap
 [java] Applying edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.ExplicitSerialization to java/util/HashMap
```

Adding `<onlyAnalyze>com.company.app.-</onlyAnalyze>` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @jreptak sorry I don't remember.